# How to prove consistency of theory with metalanguage?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

I am familiar with first-order model theory. I also know that Tarski's definition of truth was made precisely in order to avoid paradoxes related to metalanguage such as the Liar. My question is: how do you prove the consistency of a theory that has first-order predicates regarding "objects" as well as metalanguage predicates on first-order propositions such as "being conceivable"? I suppose one has to construct some kind of model, but I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

A [relative consistency proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency) can be achieved constructing a mathematical structure and showing that this structure is a model (i.e. satisfies) the axioms of the theory.

Usually, this construction will be performed in some (part of) set theory as metatheory.

Another approach can be achieved with [Proof Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/#GentConsProo); also in this case - due to [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) - the metatheory needs resources external to the object theory.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how one should construct a structure that interprets both predicates (and functions, and constants) on objects and those on propositions. Can it be done? Can you give me references to some examples?

Comment: @MatteoCasarosa - if your language can "speak of" them, why not? Maybe you have a many-sorted language with a sort for "objects" and one sort for "propositions"...

Comment: So you are saying that for example I could define the binary function on propositions "&" as a partial function defined on some subset of the domain of the structure and another partial function "f( . , . )" defined o objects as a partial function defined on another subset of the domain? I've never heard of Tarski's semantics with partial functions and predicates rather than the usual total ones. Again, could you direct me to some examples of "many-sorted" models?

Comment: See e.g. Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (Academic Press, 2nd ed 2001)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Mathematical_Introduction_to_Logic/dVncCl_EtUkC), **SECTION 4.3** Many-Sorted Logic, page 295-on.

Comment: @MatteoCasarosa - having said that, trying to deal with object language and meta-language in the same formal theory (in a consistent way9 can be quite hard...

Comment: On self-referential systems, you can see also Raymond Smullyan, [Diagonalization and Self-Reference (1994)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Diagonalization_and_Self_reference/uH53QgAACAAJ)